# Credit Memo Return to stock is not working

Tags: magento-1.8, creditmemo, stock-status

When I use the credit memo to refund customer and return the qty to stock the qty is not being returned to stock.

E.g. I have 1 hat instock I sell the hat and the qty changes to 0 and status to out of stock. However when I do a return to stock via credit memo the qty stays at 0 and status out of stock. It will not update the stock when a return is made.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your configuration is set  (this option is disabled by default) :

`System -> Configuration ->  Catalog - Inventory  -> Product Stock Options -> Automatically Return Credit Memo Item to Stock`

Set to `Yes`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already checked that to Yes. I have extendware full page cache extension on the site could that be causing an error?

Comment: Well, I don't think Full page cache is the pb. Your creditmemo should be made in the  magento back end interface where you can check quantities refunded.

Answer (score 1):

You can issue a credit memo in two ways.

**1.** Click on 'Credit Memo' from the `Order` view.

**2.** Click in 'Credit Memo' from the `Order Invoice` view.

The Credit Memo needs a reference to the invoice that took the item out of stock in the first place.  Only the second one will do that and return the item to stock.  The first one doesn't reference the invoice.

You can get to the `Order Invoice` view by clicking `Invoices` in the left navigation when viewing an Order.